# How to push Windows 10 notifications to an Android phone?

Tags: windows, android, windows-10, notification

I want to mirror Windows 10 notifications I get on my PC to my Android phone. Is there a software that can do it? (I use IFTTT, Tasker, Pushbullet, Cortana but they can't do what I want) Or some another way to do it? I'm open to ideas. If you have multiple solutions, I would like to know them all. (btw I can't code other than copying and pasting a piece of code to powershell) Thanks in advance.